# C#;WebDriver: String array is coming up null when attempting to click using linktext

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read the following list:

```
<ol class="sublist">
<li>
<a href="/Home/Article.aspx?    level=3XAP2FPAX6J7I3kztATGuYyXAP2BPAXDahIQXAP3DPAXXAP3DPAX&articleId=R866G0jVPwSUTNiC7yuIXAP2BPAXQXAP3DPAXXAP3DPAX">Sort Out Your Values</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/Home/Article.aspx?level=3XAP2FPAX6J7I3kztATGuYyXAP2BPAXDahIQXAP3DPAXXAP3DPAX&articleId=v2CBBm83qhsNjLKWbtfCNwXAP3DPAXXA P3DPAX">Establish Realistic Goals</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/Home/Article.aspx?  level=3XAP2FPAX6J7I3kztATGuYyXAP2BPAXDahIQXAP3DPAXXAP3DPAX&articleId=yBjSNWqdoXAP2FPAXvuZzib2H88pQXAP3DPAXXAP3DPAX">Determine Your Monthly Net Income</a>
```

This is the code i wrote for it; but currently, everytime it runs; my string is coming up empty. I want to get the inner text so that in my loop i grab it and click it and return back to previous screen.

```
IWebElement  container = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("sublist"));
IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));       
        string [] newlink = new string[elements.Count()];

        for (int i = 0; i < newlink.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (newlink[i] != null)
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(newlink[i])).Click();
                driver.WaitForElement(By.CssSelector("[id$='hlnkPrint']"));
                driver.Navigate().Back();
            }
        }
```

The script is able to run but was getting that the links were null, so i added a check to see if any of them were null and it turns out all of them are.
Im sure it has something to do with with the '.text' or 'ToString', but Im not sure where to implement that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code.
- You haven't set the value of `newlink`, just created it.
- `Count` is a property, but you're using it as a method.
- Link text is the `.Text` property of an `IWebElement`, and you would need to access that.
- Your current code will likely click one link, and after going back will throw a `StaleElementException`.

In the following
- I set `newlink` to the `Text` values of the links found for `elements`
- I then iterate through the array of link text

```
IWebElement  container = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("sublist"));
IList<IWebElement> elements = container.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));       
string[] newlink = new string[elements.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < newlink.Count; i++)
{
    newlink[i] = elements[i].Text;
}

for (int i = 0; i < newlink.Count; i++)
{
    if (newlink[i] != null)
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(newlink[i])).Click();
        driver.WaitForElement(By.CssSelector("[id$='hlnkPrint']"));
        driver.Navigate().Back();
    }
}
```

You can use `FindElement()` on an `IWebElement`.  so in this case, if you want to find elements that are children of `container`, you would use `container.FindElements()`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the code improvement you made is able to grab links. However, i am now getting links i don't want outside my container. it looks like the code is ignoring the 1st line where i declare iwebelement. My understanding with declaring iwebelement, when i use it on IList<IwebElement> that it would use the container declaration and look for tags under that. Correct me if i am wrong. PS, i need to read upon the property vs method; got confused by that.

Comment: Got it working, thank you so much. Learned a lot on your examples. I will need to get creative on my container as im sure it will be different as i have to do this for 13 other sites. Added a waitforpagetoload on my second to last loop as it was going by too fast. Thank you Richard.